# Logstash Grok распарсить строку лога

Tags: logstash, grok

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как распарсить такой формат. Не могу понять, как указать квадратные скобки и обычный текст.

**[lkb2b-adapter,89b207d068d3d6eb,1d0ae20fe29a2ba5,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] client.crm.ClientCrmRest   : [CrmRestClient#updateComment] x-powered-by: Undertow/1**

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

\[%{GREEDYDATA:field1}\] %{NUMBER:field2} --- \[%{DATA:field3}\] %{JAVACLASS:field4} : \[%{DATA:field5}\] x-powered-by: %{GREEDYDATA:x-powered-by} "

[image: Выход:]